# How to install the translations for trac

Tags: internationalization

I have installed trac on my server running Ubuntu 12.04. The problem is that the users cannot change the language in their preferences. Instead, the following message is displayed:

> Translations are currently unavailable. Trac has been localized to more than a dozen of languages but in order to be able to use them, the Babel package needs to be present when installing Trac. See TracInstall for details.

The installation has been done using the repositories of Ubuntu, but I could not find any package related to trac and babel, nor trac and anything related to internationalization.

How can I install the translations for trac?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Trac On Ubuntu](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnUbuntu), you need to install Babel (exactly what's the error message states):

```
sudo apt-get install python python-babel
sudo apt-get install trac
```

One of the important things mentioned on the same page is:

> Also take into account that python-babel should be always installed before trac if you wish to see it internationalized.

So, if after installing of `python-babel` on top of `trac` localization is still not in place, try to reinstall `trac` with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall trac
```

And if still no result, most likely you'll need to purge both packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-babel trac
```

... and make a clean install of `trac` as per above.

Comment: I tried the purge & install procedure you describe but I still cannot change the language of Trac. Then I have done the upgrade of Babel and Trac using easy_install, as explained in TracOnUbuntu, with no success again. I am surprised that there would be an order on the installation of the package, I expect apt to manage this.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps you need to destroy `Trac` database as well, and reinstall? Don't forget about backup :)

Comment: I doubt it would be related to the database because I have just created a new project with initenv, and it is also English only. Maybe the translations are not packaged in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have no idea - according to the Trac site they are.

Answer (score 0):

It's a packaging bug. Presently, `trac` package (I've checked 0.12.2-1 on oneiric and 0.12.2-1build1 on precise) does **not** include localization files.

```
$ dpkg -L trac | grep /locale/ | wc -l
0
```

See [Debian bug #644401](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=644401) for further details.

For a time being, while the new version propagates to Ubuntu repositories (bug the maintainers), I'd suggest using [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/trac) or [Ubuntu Quantal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/trac) package 0.12.3+, for which the issue is resolved. The following worked for me:

```
$ wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/trac/trac_0.12.3-1_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i trac_0.12.3-1_all.deb
$ dpkg -L trac | grep /locale/ | wc -l
261
```

(I believe it's better to put your Trac offline while the package is upgraded.)

I've filed an [Ubuntu bug #1016237](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/trac/+bug/1016237) on this subject, see the linked Launchpad bug page for its status.